# Haskell: Where is (System.)Crypto?

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I have written a one-time pad encryption module that can also generate pads. I have read that Haskell comes with some kind of cryptographically secure random number generator, whose module name contains "Crypto". So I use my GHCi and type "import " and tab to bring up all of the possible imports. There is no Crypto module, only the plain old Random. I explicitly try to import "System.Crypto" and then, just "Crypto"; no luck. I perform a text search with Power Shell on the results of the autocomplete, but it finds no applicable entry. Where is the cryptographic random number generator? If I don't have it, where can I get it? Am I imagining things?

Details:

```
GHCi
version 7.6.3
Windows 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Haskell does *not* "come with" a cryptographically secure random number generator, if by that you mean it should be included in the Haskell Platform.

[Searching for "crypto" on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=crypto) throws up a number of packages you can install with Cabal, though.  I'm not well versed in those but the top `crypto-random` one looks promising.  This doesn't necessarily mean much, though.  Although Hackage is the place to find most things Haskell, unfortunately it doesn't *yet* have good features to find out which of its packages are actually high quality. (This is expected to improve as the new Hackage 2 implementation is much more flexible than the old one.)

Answer (score -1):

If you installed Haskell platform, you can find all libraries out of box [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/).

I find there is a [System.Random](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/packages/random-1.0.1.1/doc/html/System-Random.html) package which has a global random number generator. The global random number generator is initialized automatically in some system-dependent fashion, for example, by using the time of day, or Linux's kernel random number generator.

Or you can use other packages by `cabal install` such as [crypto-api](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-api-0.3.1/docs/Crypto-Random.html).

Comment: Is the Random module cryptographically secure? I did not find any other cryptographic module from the link provided.

Comment: The `System.Random` module's `StdGen` generator is *not* cryptographically secure.  It's not considered very good even for a non-cryptographical one.